# I don't want all these lines printing everytime I run the python code in VS Code in zsh (Mac terminal)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh

[This appears every time I run a code from VS using zsh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhAko.png)

The same happens even when I run it through the integrated terminal. This does not happen when I run the code in pycharm. How to fix this, please help.

Comment: You did not write how you configured your Terminal, and how your zsh startup files look like. You fix this by tracing the execution of the zsh startup (using the `-x` option) and have a look, where this output is generated.

Comment: show your `launch.json`, somehow you configure it to pass all the environment variables, all the other text will ALWAYS be printed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are debugging your code. The outputs maybe have related to the launch.json file. Could you create a new configuration and selected it to have a test again?

Or could you just right-click and select `Run Python File in Terminal`.